Extract data from files and calculate their averages
I'm trying to make a script that creates a file that contains the average of each line of different files.
My real problem is that I don't know how to make an efficient script to process 300 files.txt of 30Mo (about 9000000 values) in a few secondes...
Here's what I would like (to clarify the real goal) :

line 1 : average_value_of_the_line_number_one_of_every_file


line 2 : average_value_of_the_line_number_two_of_every_file ...

Here's my current script (which works if you have the time to take a coffee) :
import glob
import numpy as np

# Repertory where my files are
directory = '/directory/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(directory)

# buffer
data = []

# Get the values
for file in files :
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        data.append([int(line.strip()) for line in f])

# Convert to array numpy for perf
data_np = np.array(data, dtype=np.float64).T 

# Average for each line
average = np.mean(data_np, axis=1)

# Round off averages
round_average = np.round(average).astype(int)

# fill in the new file
with open('my_new_average_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for average in round_average:
        f.write(f"{average}\n")

print("done")


Edit : Example of the input files :

value1


value2


value3 ...

The files have the same amount of lines and each line contains a single integer value (from 0 to 255)
Many thanks for your helps

Could you give an example of the input files? Each file has the same amount of lines, and each line contains a single integer value, is it right?

@cruzlorite I edited the post (as you can see now, an input file has only 1 value(integer) in each line, and they all have the same amount of lines so about 9000000). Thanks

It's highly unlikely that you'll achieve your objective of processing 300 files each containing 30,000 values in a "few seconds" with Python

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Dask is really good for this kind of thing since it automatically parallelizes I/O and computation...
This is your example code adapted to use Dask Bags and it finishes computation in 10-12sec on my machine (provided the text files already exist).
Getting the average per file with Dask requires a little extra work involving partitions. Dask can handle this by treating each file as a partition and computes the mean of each partition using the map_partition function instead of just map...
import math
import os.path
import numpy as np
import dask.bag as db

num_files = 300
lines_in_file = 30_000
overwrite_files = False #set to true to overwrite existing text files
average_per_file = True #false computes average across all files
data_directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'directory')
# print(data_directory)

# %%
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    if not os.path.exists(data_directory):
        os.makedirs(data_directory)

    #create 300 files with 30_000 lines each, each line contains a random number between 0 and 255
    for i in range(num_files):
        outfile = os.path.join(data_directory, f'file_{i}.txt')
        if os.path.exists(outfile) and overwrite_files==False:
            continue
        with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
            for j in range(lines_in_file):
                f.write(f"{np.random.randint(0, 255)}\n")
                
    data = db.read_text(f"{data_directory}/file_*.txt")

    def convert(file):
        return [int(line.strip()) for line in file]

    def average(file):
        #must be used after calling convert since is expecting a list of ints
        return np.mean(np.array(file))

    if average_per_file:
        #read_text reads in each file as a partition, 
        #so per partition operations as equivalent to per file operations
        data = data.map_partitions(convert) #remove whitespace and convert to int (for each line in partition), returns list of ints per file
        average = data.map_partitions(average) #computes mean per partition (file)
        computed_avg = average.compute() #compute final result
        print(f"averages: {computed_avg}")
        computed_avg = np.round(computed_avg).astype(int)
    else:
        data = data.map(lambda x: int(x.strip())) #remove whitespace and convert to int (for each line)
        average = data.mean() #lazy queue mean function
        computed_avg = average.compute() #compute result
        print(f"average: {computed_avg}")
        computed_avg = np.round(computed_avg).astype(int)

    #fill in the new file
    with open('my_new_average_file.txt', 'w') as f:
        if average_per_file:
            for average in computed_avg:
                f.write(f"{average}\n")
        else:
            f.write(f"{computed_avg}\n")

    print("done")


I didn't read the question carefully... Now I see you're aiming for the average of each line number across the files
